# AWS SQS dump/restore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to dump a SQS queue to open space for "urgent" messages and then restore the dump to keep SQS queue on track?

I am not talking about aws cli commands but any possibility of doing it.

Of course I could open a new SQS and change the application to look after that new queue, but it would have some implications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. The design pattern I've seen AWS recommend when you want to have "high priority" messages is this:

- Create 2 queues, one for high-priority messages and one for regular-priority messages.
- Have your application always scan the high-priority queue first to check for new messages.
- If you don't receive any messages from the high-priority queue, scan the regular-priority queue for messages.

Comment: This pattern doesn't work if you're using long polling.  I poll both queues simultaneously with multiple receiveMessageAsync calls.

Comment: @Krum Even short poling can miss certain messages from SQS's distributed queues. Why wouldn't long polling work?

Comment: @KeetSugathadasa he probably just means that it slows things down considerably if you are using long polling in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

AWS SQS does not provide a priority based queue at the moment. But you can do certain implementations and build a priority queue for your application (consumer). Following are some implementations you can use.

1) As [@Markb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mark-b) mentioned, you can create **two SQSs**, where one is for high priority messages and other is for regular messages. Make sure application polls the high-priority SQS first and then move on to the regular SQS.

2) If using a **single SQS**, have a few worker threads on the application side, that will collect all the messages from SQS, and process them to see which ones have a higher priority. Take them and process first.

3) Use a combination of **SQS and SNS**. Send all the regular messages into the SQS. If there are high priority messages, send them to SNS to direct them to a specific endpoint in your application. From you application side (consumer side), have and endpoint that listens to high priority messages coming from SNS, and then have aprocess that polls the SQS to retrieve the regular messages.